# What is the difference between @RequestMapping and @RenderMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When should I use @RequestMapping instead of @RenderMapping and vice versa ?

For example what is the difference between the following where one method uses @RequestMapping and the other uses @RenderMapping

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public click myController {

@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public String showView(final ModelMap argMap, final RenderRequest argRequest) { 
    return "myView"
}

}
```

and :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public click myController {

@RenderMapping("VIEW")
public String showView(final ModelMap argMap, final RenderRequest argRequest) { 
    return "myView"
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RenderMapping is a method level annotation which is used to map render requests to render methods of handler class.

The @RequestMapping annotation maps portlet requests to appropriate handlers and handler methods.

Please check this for more details

http://books.dzone.com/articles/spring-30-portlet-mvc-part-2